# variable vlookup VBA in closed file on server

Tags: file, vba, variables, vlookup

I have been looking for awhile now and could not find a working solution for my exact situation.

```
    VLOOKUP(Data!B4,'\\server\Log\[file - 2013.xls]1206'!$B:$F,3,FALSE)
```

This function works to lookup information in a closed file in cell, but wanting to make the sheet "1206" be variable to a date code, MMDD. And Perhaps making the file also variable, not sure yet.

MY GOAL: Is to make a lookup function that will search multiple files on a CLOSED file from a server and tell me what sheet it found the word on.

```
    datecode = "1206"
    :find
    If "VLOOKUP(Data!B4,'\\server\Log\[file - 2013.xls]" & datecode & "'!$B:$F,3,FALSE)" > 0
    'Is NOT an ERROR
    MsgBox datecode
    else
    datecode = (datecode + 1)
    Goto find 
    End if
```

some problems I have had :
""  erroring out or showing/not showing up at the right times
'   at the begining of file name erroring out

I am very new to VBA and don't fully under stand what/how strings, Dim, FormulaR1C1, and my.formula
Wanting to learn for need a code I can use and edit/understand.
Thank you for your time.
Question also asked at http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?48547-Variable-vlookup-in-VBA-in-closed-file&p=302425#post302425

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you want to achieve...

If you are new to VBA, I assume you would like to imitate some excel behaviour and use formulas to determine whether something exists. If this is the case, I suggest you generate the formulas into cells, as VBA on its own is not design to evaluate formulas (even though you have methods like Evaluate or Module WorksheetFunctions). This would then be something like:

```
datecode = "1206"
find:
with Thisworkbook.Sheets("TestSheet").Cells(1,1)
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(Data!B4,'\\server\Log\[file - 2013.xls]" & datecode & "'!$B:$F,3,FALSE)" > 0
    If Vba.IsError(.Value) then
        datecode = (datecode + 1)
        Goto find 
    End If
end with
```

Give it a try. This is not the best solution, but at least should work...

Comment: It wont as the OP wants to *`search multiple files on a CLOSED file from a server`